# tailwind.config.js file not being generated

Tags: tailwind-css

I installed tailwindcss on my next.js project but I couldn't find the tailwind.config.js file. Here is the command I used to install

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

Please I need help guys

Comment: Read the documentation: [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration). As L. Letovanec said below, you need to run `npx tailwindcss init`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to run `npx tailwindcss init` to generate the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `npx tailwindcss init` to generate the configuration file. If the file is generated but your application, especially a React application, is unable to read the classes, you might want to follow the instructions provided here. Although they may seem a bit unusual, they work. Refer to the [Tailwind CSS documentation](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) for more details.